# Email Subscription Service Failures - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are currently using SQL Server Reporting Services.  We routinely (daily) experience failures of numerous subscription reports during various times of the day/night.   There are times when several of the same reports fail. The failures are intermittent and don't exhibit any specific pattern. When we re-schedule the reports to run almost immediately, sometimes we receive subsequent failures and sometimes the reports running successfully.

The status is: **Failure sending mail: One or more errors occurred. Mail will not be resent.**

We have opened the LOG file in here -> *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\Reporting Services\LogFiles look for filename: ReportServerService*.log*

The following error message shows up for each failure in the

---

> **ERROR: Error sending email. 
>   Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.** ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 
>   The server committed a protocol violation 
>   The server response was: 
>   at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: **The server committed a protocol violation The server response was:** 
>      at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)<---
>   . Additional Information: SmtpException StatusCode:GeneralFailure

---

Unfortunately, the error is very vague and is extremely difficult to troubleshoot. Due to this on-going problem, we have to re-run up to about 20 reports daily. We have conducted extensive research and analysis of our report and SMTP server configurations but are still unable to resolve this annoying problem. 
If anyone has experienced this issue and/or can provide some insight on how to permanently solve it, please let me know as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Daniel, try this answer [link] https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/edff6181-4b1c-43cb-a958-c93b60c67e5d/why-is-my-ssrs-email-subscription-not-sending-email?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 1):

Obviously late, but this was probably caused when microsoft forced everything to TLS 1.2 and degraded 1.0
The fix was to add the below dwords to the registry so it wouldn't attempt TLS 1.0

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```

Comment: this fixed it for me on a Windows 22 server...idk why this didnt come set up in the registry...